# Can't add android platform to phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to add the android platform to my phonegap project. I've added already the iOS platform which worked without any problems. When trying to add android via command

```
phonegap local run android
```

I'm always getting this error:

```
[error] The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and    the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path.
```

I have already downloaded the latest Android SDK and I set a PATH to the tools and platform-tools folder as well.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Documents/android/sdk/platform-tools:/Documents/android/sdk/tools
```

I also updated my bash_profile file properly with

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the path to the Android SDK have to be absolute path. After changing my path to something like

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/your-username/Documents/android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/your-username/Documents/android/sdk/tools
```

I could now successfully add the android platform to my project.